# Is there an efficient way to generate number of factors of N less than X?

Tags: c++, number-theory

I am a **beginner** in the field of programming. I just want to find the number of factors / divisors of a positive integer `N` less than `X`. (`X` itself is a factor of `N`). I have a naive approach which doesn't work good for queries on `N`,`X`.

Here is my approach

```
int Divisors(int n, int x) {
    int ans = 0;
    if (x < sqrt(n)) {
        for (int i = 1; i < x; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                ans++;
            }
        }
    } else
        for (int i = 1; i <= sqrt(n); i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                if (n / i == i && i < x)
                    ans++;
                else {
                    if (i < x)
                        ans++;
                    if (n / i < x)
                        ans++;
                }
            }
        }
    return ans;
}
```

Is there some efficient way to do this? Kindly help me out!

**The actual problem I'm trying to solve :**
Given some `M` and `N` I need to iterate through all positive integers  less than or equal to `N`(`1 <= i <= N`) and I need to count how many numbers less than the current number (`i`) exists such that they divide the last multiple of `i` that is less than or equal to `M` (i.e., `M - M % i`) and finally find the sum of all counts.

**Example**
Given `N = 5` and `M = 10`
**Ans : 6**

Explanation :

`i = 1 count = 0`

`i = 2 count = 1` (10 % 1 = 0)

`i = 3 count = 1` (9 % 1 = 0)

`i = 4 count = 2` (8 % 1 = 0, 8 % 2 = 0)

`i = 5 count = 2` (10 % 1 = 0, 10 % 2 = 0)

Therefore sum of all counts = 6

Comment: why does it not work good?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 my algorithm's best case time complexity would be O(sqrt(N)). For Q queries it would take O(Q * sqrt(n)). I am looking for a better algorithm please.

Comment: Don't you need `x <= sqrt(n)` in both cases? Methinks you're also missing a `}` - it's a good idea to use braces on the `true` part of an `if` if you need them on the `false` part.

Comment: To start with, find the prime factorization of X. (The prime factorization is a list of primes that divide X, including powers or repetition counts. For example, the prime factorization of 792 is 2³×3²×11¹.) Then, since X is a factor of N, remove it to give N/X and find the prime factorization of N/X, but stopping when primes would exceed X. Add that to the prime factorization of X (add the repetition counts). The result is a list of primes and repetition counts, say p0^r0•p1^r1•p2^r2•… Then candidate factors are p0^i0•p1^i1•p2^i2•… for 0≤i0≤r0, 0≤i1≤r1, and so on…

Comment: Then write code to take the list of primes and repetition counts and iterate an array of [i0, i1, i2,…] subject to the bounds above and also bounding the product to be less than X. Iterating the array can be done “odometer style,” where the last element in the array is incremented and, if it exceeds its bound or the product exceeds X, it is reset to zero and the iteration operation moves to the previous element in the array. When the iteration operation would move before the first element of the array, the iterations are complete.

Comment: (By the way, while finding the prime factorization of some number T, do not keep dividing numbers into T. Each time a prime factor is found, divide T by that factor.)

Comment: To add to @EricPostpischil answer: 1) find all primes <= sqrt(MAX_X), and save it in a file, there are plenty of ways to do this and complexity on this step is not important 2) use result of (1) to find factorization of N and X, it is sim[le to do this with O(log(X)) complexity. Eric already described what to do with factorization on hand.

Comment: For a single run I do not think you can do better than a worst case complexity of O(sqrt(n)). From your comment, it seems you are looking for an improvement over several runs. In that case, you should edit the question to clarify the problem. Maybe also add an example with expected divisors for a couple of different inputs. The question is not very clear.

Comment: @nielsen I have edited the question by adding the actual problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

The wording of the question is a bit confusing.
I'm assuming you are finding the size of the set of all factors/divisors, **D**, of a number *n* that are less than a number *x*, where *x* is a factor of *n*.

An easier way of doing this is to iterate from all numbers 1 through *x*, exclusive of *x*, and use the modulo operator `%`.

Code:

```
int NumOfDiv(int x, int n){
  int count = 0;

  for(int i=1; i<x; i++){
    if(n % i == 0)  //This indicates that i divides n, having a remainder of 0, 
                      look up % as it is very useful with number theory
      count++;
  }

  return count;
}
```

Example:

`int TestNum = NumOfDiv(4,12)`

`TestNum` would have the value of `3`

Comment: I see now that you are trying to optimize this and I think there is a confusion on factors and divisors.  If you are trying to find all prime number divisors, I would suggest first creating a list of prime numbers <x

Comment: Sorry, but your solution is worse than the OP. It is slower and wrong since you have the wrong order of operands: `i % n == 0` tests if `n` divides `i`, not the other way around. The OP did not make that mistake.

Comment: Thank you for catching my mistake.  I did not see it when I posted.  I also did not realize that OP was looking for optimization of the algorithm at the time.

Comment: I have made changes to the question adding an example of the actual problem I'm trying to solve.